# Do not cast fields starting with underscore to ObjectID in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have JSON from foreign MongoDB that contains fields starting with underscore like "_item" with hash of ObjectID.

I want to save such JSON to my local MongoDB but Mongoose tries to cast those fields to ObjectIDs (by following underscored fields convention https://gist.github.com/bclinkinbeard/5171359) and throwing `MongooseError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value` error.
In schema I define that field as String `_item: {type: String}`.

I want to store those fields as simple strings instead of references. Can I do that without transforming field names?

Comment: Which version of _Mongoose_? I tried but can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @TGrif version 4.9.3

Comment: It works fine when I try that. The code you linked is a just an example that's using a convention of using a leading underscore for references. Can you provide a [MCVE]?